# I can't figure out how to output the number of objects and highlight them in different colors

Tags: python, opencv, colors

I wrote a code that looks for objects in the video. I have a problem with the output of the number of objects found (I can't bring it to mind). Could you please help?

I also tried to make sure that each object was highlighted in its own color. To do this, I took the numpy library and tried to make different colors for different objects through random, but as a result, each object shimmered with different colors.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

thres = 0.5
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #  ||| cap = cv2.VideoCapture("VIDEO0102.mp4");
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)
cap.set(10, 70)

classNames = []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames=[line.rstrip() for line in f]

configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=thres)
    print(classIds, bbox)


    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
            cv2.rectangle(img, box, color=(12, 0, 0), thickness=1)
            cv2.putText(img, classNames[classId - 1].upper(), (box[0] + 10, box[1] + 30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, str(round(confidence * 100, 2)), (box[0] + 200, box[1] + 30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (210, 70, 60), 2) 
    cv2.imshow("Output", img) 
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```